# disable or enable capture button in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using Gyroscope to determine my ipad is perpendicular (attitude of 88 to 92 degree) or not .
if it is then can take picture.
I have something like a traffic light red or green to show permission of take picture but I can not disable capture button when the light is red
any help would be appreciated

here is my code

```
@IBAction func camera1(_ sender: Any) {
        var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:50, height:50));
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = imageView
            imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = imagePicker.cameraViewTransform.scaledBy(x: 3, y: 3);
        
        //Gyroscop
        func myGyroscope() {
            motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2
            motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue()) { (motion, error) -> Void in
                       if let attitude = motion?.attitude {
                       // print(attitude.roll * 180 / Double.pi)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            if (((attitude.roll * 180 / Double.pi) * -1) > 88 && ((attitude.roll * 180 / Double.pi) * -1) < 92 ){
                                imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "GREEN_Light")//Take picture is permitted
                            } else{
                                imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Red_Light")//Take picture is not permitted
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                   }
        myGyroscope()
    
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            frontpic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                if (picker.sourceType.rawValue == 1){//if camera
                        frontpic.image = pickedImage.cropedToRatio(ratio: 0.33)
                } else{//if album
                        frontpic.image = pickedImage
                }
                
        }
       
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interfere with the built in camera controls. If you don't like way they behave, [remove them](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619129-showscameracontrols) and substitute your own interface as part of the `cameraOverlayView`.

Comment: yes you are right but I don't know can I have all functions in built in camera like auto focus or changing brightness and others ?
all of functions are useful except  this one that I want to manage it.
Is there any code example?
I am so new in ios